# How do you figure out the headers needed for HTTP requests when there's no documentation

Tags: javascript, api, react-native

There's no documentation for this API, and many other API's available. How do you figure out the HTTP headers required for a successful GET (and others) request?

For example: I can request XML from the following API endpoint using the following cURL

`curl -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -X GET http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML\?StationDesc\=Bray`

http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=Bray

But I receive a

`TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror` when attempting to GET request through code.

Here is the request metadata I'm using:

`method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/xml",
      "Content-Type": "application/xml"`

Comment: That URL has no CORS response header so it cannot be called client side from a browser. Your "Content-Type" is not valid because your not sending XML.

Comment: If you click the link you do receive xml to the browser. Ok, I've removed the content-type, it still works with or without that header using cURL. Still doesn't work requested in code.

Comment: Aye but you are not going to be able to request it through Ajax in the browser because its cross origin (i.e. it does not allow requests from other domains)

Comment: Where are you seeing that it has no CORS header? Are you saying that they've blocked access to the API? I'm almost 100% sure that's not the case, they allow anyone to use the real time data.

Comment: If I run an ajax request in the error console I see: *Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=Bray. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)*

Comment: There are public APIs that can be called via Ajax, this does not appear to be one, its likely intended to be called from a server (or anything other than a browser that does not care about CORS)

Comment: I'm calling it from a react native app that likely uses native iOS networking. Thanks for running the request man

Comment: Well your error does mention XMLHttpRequest so its using ajax somewhere and that may breal cross origin.